# Change linked object to appended?

Tags: linked-data, append

I have linked maybe 20 objects into one blender file, but now I want to change it to appended objects. I want to use this blender file in Unity, and it seems the objects get broken if I include linked objects.

Is there a way to change linked objects into appended objects, or any way to separate them from the original file, or to import Unity in any better way?

Comment: Simply put, appended objects are full copies of original ones, without any connection with source as opposed to linked, that is stated [in the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) . That's why the solution could be to use Make Local operator what David suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a operator accessible from the 3D view header *Object* > *Make Local* > *All*  (or <kbd>L</kbd>) that will make the linked objects local copies.  **Do note that this is **not** undoable.**

[image: Make Local]

The difference between the options is not stated in the manual.

- **Selected objects** Only make the object local, you can move, scale and add modifiers, but all the mesh data, materials, etc stays linked to the source file. (you can not enter edit mode.)
- **All** copies everything and there are no links for *any* objects. All linked objects are now editable.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I exactly wanted to do. Could see it works also in Unity now.

Comment: Thanks. What if all these options are gray (unclickable)?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what type of object you linked, just select said objects and press <kbd>L</kbd> to open the *Make Local* menu and choose second option *Objects and Data*.

If you linked a *Group Instance* or *Collection Instance*, first select it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to make duplicates real.

For 2.8+ you can find these options under the *3D View* menu *Object > Relations > Make Local... > Object and Data* or  *Object > Apply > Make Instances Real*.