# Why can't a linked group be used as a dynamic paint brush?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linked-data, groups, dynamic-paint

I have created a character for my 30second short that is my final in my Blender Graphics 3D Design class in a separate blend file from the landscape it resides in.  I am trying to make it so the character is carving out a path in the landscape, but where I have linked this character group it will not allow access to all of the physics options.  I'm using Cycles Render to get a more life like effect.

Am I going to have to go into the original character file in order to make it into a dynamic paint brush, and if I do will it work with having the dynamic canvas in the blend file the character file is linked to? Or is there another way around this issue?

Comment: Have your tried linking as individual proxy objects instead of linking as a whole group?

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now.  I ended up answering my own question after taking a breather and searching through similar questions.  I ended up linking the group then duplicating it, after making it local, so it could act as the digital paint brush.  The answer I found most helpful was http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46945/change-linked-object-to-appended   The first answer to it was most helpful for my distraught soul.