# How to ungroup a group instance

Tags: objects, edit-mode, groups, instances

I've created a group consisting of a few objects, then created a few instances of that group. I now want to "ungroup" one of the instances, de-linking all of that instance's objects from the parent group, leaving them at their current location, and creating a bunch of objects that can be edited individually.

1. Is this possible?
2. How do you do it?

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+A Make duplicates real

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46945/change-linked-object-to-appended/46948#46948

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to [Make duplicates real](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#make-duplicate-real).

Originally from [this comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100130/how-to-ungroup-a-group-instance/101798#comment177072_100130)

Comment: While this is the answer, why not take the time to make it a bit more useful? See my edit.